# Was Schrodinger right?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

\begin{eqnarray*}
x\left( r,\theta ,\varphi \right) &=&r\sin \theta \cos \varphi \\
y\left( r,\theta ,\varphi \right) &=&r\sin \theta \sin \varphi \\
z\left( r,\theta ,\varphi \right) &=&r\cos \theta g\left( \varphi \right)
=r\cos \theta
\end{eqnarray*}

where $g\left( \varphi \right) =1$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan \varphi &=&\frac{x}{y} \\
\partial _{x}\tan \varphi &=&\frac{1}{y} \\
\frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\varphi }\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x} &=&\frac{1}{%
r\sin \theta \sin \varphi }\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial
x}=\frac{\cos ^{2}\varphi }{r\sin \theta \sin \varphi } \\
\frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}} &=& \\
\partial _{y}\tan \varphi &=&-\frac{x}{y^{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\varphi }\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y} &=&-\frac{%
r\sin \theta \cos \varphi }{r^{2}\sin ^{2}\theta \sin ^{2}\varphi }%
\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}=-\frac{\cos ^{3}\varphi 
}{r\sin \theta \sin ^{2}\varphi } \\
\frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial y^{2}} &=& \\
\partial _{z}\tan \varphi &=&0 \\
\frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\varphi }\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}
&=&0\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}=0\Longrightarrow 
\frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial z^{2}}=0
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{z^{2}} &=&\tan ^{2}\theta \\
\partial _{x}\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{z^{2}} &=&\partial _{x}\tan ^{2}\theta \\
\frac{2x}{z^{2}} &=&2\tan \theta \partial _{\theta }\tan \theta \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x} \\
\frac{x}{z^{2}} &=&\tan \theta \partial _{\theta }\tan \theta \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x} \\
\frac{\sin \theta \cos \varphi }{r\cos ^{2}\theta } &=&\frac{\sin \theta }{%
\cos ^{3}\theta }\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x} &=&\frac{\cos \theta \cos \varphi }{r} \\
\partial _{y}\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{z^{2}} &=&\partial _{y}\tan ^{2}\theta \\
\frac{y}{z^{2}} &=&\tan \theta \partial _{\theta }\tan \theta \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial y} \\
\frac{\sin \theta \sin \varphi }{r\cos ^{2}\theta } &=&\frac{\sin \theta }{%
\cos ^{3}\theta }\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y} &=&\frac{\cos \theta \sin \varphi }{r} \\
\partial _{z}\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{z^{2}} &=&\partial _{z}\tan ^{2}\theta \\
-2\left( x^{2}+y^{2}\right) z^{-3} &=&2\tan \theta \partial _{\theta }\tan
\theta \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z} \\
-\left( x^{2}+y^{2}\right) z^{-3} &=&\tan \theta \partial _{\theta }\tan
\theta \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z} \\
-\frac{\sin ^{2}\theta }{r\cos ^{3}\theta } &=&\frac{\sin \theta }{\cos
^{3}\theta }\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z} &=&-\frac{\sin \theta }{r}
\end{eqnarray*}

$$\[
\frac{\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial x^{2}} 
\]$$

$$\[
\frac{\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial y^{2}} 
\]$$

\bigskip
\begin{eqnarray*}
r &=&\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\partial _{x}r &=&x\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sin
\theta \cos \varphi \\
\partial _{y}r &=&y\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sin
\theta \sin \varphi \\
\partial _{z}r &=&z\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\cos
\theta \\
\left( \partial _{x}r\right) ^{2}+\left( \partial _{y}r\right) ^{2}+\left(
\partial _{z}r\right) ^{2} &=&1 \\
\partial _{x}^{2}r &=&\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left[
1-\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right] \\
\partial _{y}^{2}r &=&\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left[
1-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right] \\
\partial _{z}^{2}r &=&\left( x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left[
1-\frac{z^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}\right] \\
\left( \partial _{x}^{2}+\partial _{y}^{2}+\partial _{z}^{2}\right) r &=&2/r
\end{eqnarray*}%
\begin{eqnarray*}
r &=&r\left( x,y,z\right) \\
dr &=&\left. \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right\vert _{y,z}dx+\left. \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial y}\right\vert _{x,z}dy+\left. \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial z}\right\vert _{x,y}dz \\
\left. \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right\vert _{y,z} &=&\frac{1}{\left(
\left. \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right\vert _{y,z}\right) ^{-1}}=u\left(
x,y,z\right) =U\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right)
,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip

$$\[
F\left( x,y,z\right) =F\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left(
x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) 
\]$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{x}^{2}F\left( x,y,z\right) &=&\partial _{x}\left[ \partial
_{x}F\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left(
x,y,z\right) \right) \right] \\
&=&\partial _{x}\left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( 
\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \right] \\
&=&\partial _{x}\left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{%
\partial \theta }\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{%
\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}%
\right) \right] \\
&=&\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left(
x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial ^{2}r%
}{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta
\left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta
\left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip

$$\[
\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left( x,y,z\right)
,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \right) =%
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial
r\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) 
\]$$

$$\[
\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) =\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( 
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta
^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F%
}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial
x}\right) 
\]$$

$$\[
\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) =\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left( 
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta
\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{%
\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial x}\right) 
\]$$

\bigskip

\bigskip

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\partial _{x}^{2}F \\
&=&\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left(
x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial ^{2}r%
}{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta
\left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\partial _{x}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( r\left(
x,y,z\right) ,\theta \left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right)
\right) \right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( r\left( x,y,z\right) ,\theta
\left( x,y,z\right) ,\varphi \left( x,y,z\right) \right) \left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}r}{\partial
x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{%
\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial
x}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }%
\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial r%
}{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) +%
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial
\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{x}^{2}F &=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial
\theta }\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial
\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}r}{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{%
\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial
x}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }%
\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial x^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial r%
}{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) +%
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial x}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial
\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{y}^{2}F &=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial y}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial
\theta }\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial y}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial
\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial y}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}r}{\partial y^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right) +\frac{%
\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial
y}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }%
\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial y}\right) +\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial y^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{\partial r%
}{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}\right) +%
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial y}\right) +\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial y}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial
\varphi }\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{z}^{2}F &=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left( \frac{%
\partial r}{\partial z}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\left( 
\frac{\partial ^{2}r}{\partial z^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{%
\partial z}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial z^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left( \frac{\partial \varphi 
}{\partial z}\right) ^{2}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial z^{2}}\right) \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left\{ \left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial z}\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left\{ \left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\varphi }{\partial z}\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left\{ \left( 
\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{%
\partial z}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) \left( 
\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) \right\}
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\left( \partial _{x}^{2}+\partial _{y}^{2}+\partial _{z}^{2}\right) F \\
&=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right)
^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right) ^{2}\right\} +\frac{%
\partial F}{\partial r}\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial ^{2}r}{\partial x^{2}}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}r}{\partial y^{2}}\right) +\left( \frac{%
\partial ^{2}r}{\partial z^{2}}\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta ^{2}}\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}%
\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) ^{2}\right\} +%
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta }\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\theta 
}{\partial x^{2}}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial y^{2}}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\theta }{\partial z^{2}}\right) \right\}
\\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \varphi ^{2}}\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial
\varphi }{\partial x}\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}%
\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) ^{2}\right\}
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial \varphi }\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial
^{2}\varphi }{\partial x^{2}}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{%
\partial y^{2}}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial ^{2}\varphi }{\partial z^{2}}%
\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \theta }\left\{ \left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial x}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}%
\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r%
}{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right)
+\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial z}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r\partial \varphi }\left\{ \left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}%
\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial
\varphi }{\partial x}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}%
\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r%
}{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial y}\right)
+\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial r}{%
\partial z}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{%
\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right) \right\} \\
&&+\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial \theta \partial \varphi }\left\{ \left( 
\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{%
\partial x}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial x}\right) \left( 
\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial x}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right) +\left( 
\frac{\partial \theta }{\partial y}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{%
\partial y}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}\right)
\left( \frac{\partial \theta }{\partial z}\right) +\left( \frac{\partial
\theta }{\partial z}\right) \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}%
\right) \right\} \\
&=&\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial F}{%
\partial r}+... \\
&=&\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}r^{2}\frac{\partial F}{%
\partial r}+...
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip If atoms are spherical, then $\Psi \left( r,\theta ,\varphi \right)
=F\left( r\right) $, and the eigenvalue equation for energy reads

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\left\{ \frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{%
r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\right\} -\frac{e^{2}}{r}F &=&EF \\
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r%
}+\left( \frac{2me^{2}}{\hbar ^{2}}\right) \frac{1}{r}F+\frac{2mE}{\hbar ^{2}%
}F &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}

But, let%
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{B} &\equiv &\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{me^{2}} \\
A\left( E\right) &\equiv &\frac{mE}{\hbar ^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[ A\left( E\right) \right] &=&\left[ \frac{mE}{\hbar ^{2}}\right] =%
\frac{M^{2}L^{2}T^{-2}}{M^{4}L^{8}T^{-4}}=\left( M^{2}L^{6}T^{-2}\right)
^{-1} \\
\left[ e^{2}\right] &=&\left[ mar^{2}\right] =MLT^{-2}L^{2}=ML^{3}T^{-2} \\
\left[ \frac{e^{2}}{r}\right] &=&\frac{ML^{3}T^{-2}}{L}=ML^{2}T^{-2}=\left[ E%
\right] \\
\left[ \hbar \right] &=&\left[ px\right] =\left[ ET\right] =M^{2}L^{4}T^{-2}
\\
\left[ \hbar ^{2}\right] &=&M^{4}L^{8}T^{-4} \\
\left[ a_{B}\right] &=&\left[ \frac{\hbar ^{2}}{me^{2}}\right] =\frac{%
M^{4}L^{8}T^{-4}}{MML^{3}T^{-2}}=M^{2}L^{5}T^{-2} \\
\left[ -\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\triangle \right] &=&\frac{M^{4}L^{8}T^{-4}}{%
ML^{2}}=M^{3}L^{6}T^{-4} \\
\left[ E\right] &=&M^{2}L^{2}T^{-2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Then,%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial ^{2}F}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r%
}+\left( \frac{2}{\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{me^{2}}}\right) \frac{1}{r}F+\frac{2mE}{%
\hbar ^{2}}F &=&0 \\
\frac{\partial ^{2}F\left( r\right) }{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{%
\partial F\left( r\right) }{\partial r}+\left( \frac{1}{a_{B}}\right) \frac{2%
}{r}F\left( r\right) +\frac{2}{A\left( E\right) }F\left( r\right) &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip

Note that%
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left[ \frac{2}{A\left( E\right) }\right]  &=&\left[ \left( \frac{1}{a_{B}}%
\right) \frac{2}{r}\right] \Longrightarrow \left[ \frac{1}{r}\right] =\left[ 
\frac{a_{B}}{A\left( E\right) }\right] \Longrightarrow M^{2}L^{6}T^{-2}\left[
a_{B}\right] =\left[ \frac{1}{r}\right]  \\
\left[ r\right]  &=&\frac{1}{M^{2}L^{6}T^{-2}\left[ a_{B}\right] }=\frac{1}{%
M^{2}L^{6}T^{-2}M^{2}L^{5}T^{-2}}=\frac{1}{M^{4}L^{11}T^{-4}}\text{?}
\end{eqnarray*}

There are no spherical
atoms! Yeah! Different units do not add in Schrodinger's eq.

\bigskip

If Heisenberg was right, then%
$$\[
\left[ r\right] =L=\frac{1}{M^{4}L^{11}T^{-4}}\Longrightarrow
1=M^{4}L^{12}T^{-4}\Longrightarrow M=TL^{-3} 
\]$$

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail?

Comment: One cannot add apples with oranges.;)

Comment: kudos for typing this all up, but are you aware nobody will read a wall of equations?

Comment: You don't need to show all the unnecessary steps. Just say after doing X, this is the result

Comment: I have no  idea why you put in all that coordinate transformation stuff, which is available all over the web and in text books.  Please note that we do not do check-my-work type questions here.

Answer (score 3):

This started off as a comment, but I believe it sort of answers the "question". I'm not sure what purpose the wall of equations serves, except to get to the Schrodinger Equation in spherical coordinates, which you could have just stated.

Nevertheless, if I've understood this right, you seem to claim there is a problem with adding two of the terms in this equation since they don't have the same dimensions, but don't you think this would have been noticed if it were the case? Furthermore, the Schrodinger Equation is itself dimensionally consistent, so I cannot see how putting in an assumption ("atoms are spherical") could lead to it becoming dimensionally inconsistent.

Or rather, the only way I can see that happening is if you've made a mistake in your calculations, and this is exactly what has happened. To "answer" your question, you seem to think that $$\frac{1}{A(E)} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \frac{1}{a_B}\times\frac{1}{r}$$ should have the same dimensions. This is not true, and you can verify it by just looking carefully at the equations and the way that you've defined $A(E)$ and $a_B$. Indeed, it is rather $$A(E) \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad \frac{1}{a_B}\times\frac{1}{r}$$ that shoud have the same dimensions. And, using your own calculations, you have that:

$$[A(E)] = (M^2 L^6 T^{-2})^{-1} \quad \quad [a_B] = M^2 L^5 T^{-2},$$ so it should be quite trivial for you to see that indeed $$\left[A(E)\right] = \left[ \frac{1}{a_B}\times \frac{1}{r}\right].$$

---

A piece of advice: *always* be skeptical of your own calculations. If you feel that you have "disproved" some well-established result using some "elementary" argument, more often than not you have either misunderstood it, or made a mistake in your calculations. I find this sort of humility helps you learn a lot more in the long run; it certainly helped me when I was starting off with Physics.

Comment: That last paragraph is really well said.

Comment: What dimensions does <r^2> have?

Comment: @pathint Well, given that it's the expectation value of the square of the radial *distance*, it would have dimensions of  $L^2$, though I fail to see how that is relevant to your post...